# resolve <async_generator object ...>

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a Function that yields:

`<async_generator object functionOne at 0x000001CC289F8D30>`

Is it possible to resolve the async_generator object, such that the array it contains is accessible?

Comment: Please show us your actual code. Without it all responses are just wild guesses.

Answer (score 3):

There is no any array behind it (it's a generator, lazy by design), you should iterate this object with `async for` or manually, using `__aiter__()` and `__anext__()`.
This probably will work for you:

```py
async_generator_iterator = <your_async_generator_function>()
res = [i async for i in async_generator_iterator]
```

if you want to evaluate that outside of async context, just wrap it with async function and run in event loop:

```py
async def get_result_async(asyncgen):
    return [i async for i in asyncgen]

def get_result_sync(asyncgen):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = get_result_async(asyncgen)
    res = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
    return res
    
async def functionOne():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

asyncgen = functionOne()
get_result_sync(asyncgen)

# => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you.
If I iterate over the result, it returns 
```<async_generator object functionOne at 0x000002CC57BC1790>
<async_generator object functionOne at 0x000002CC57BE8B80>```.

If I use __anext__(), I get ```<async_generator_asend object at 0x00000164AC39F480>```


Now I am a little bit confused

Comment: `Generator.__next__()` == `Generator.send(None)`;  `__anext__` returns an awaitable. Please read the [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#asynchronous-generator-object).